# How to style form inside modal with Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I place [this form](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsiampolu/qx4LP/1/) using modal.In order to do so I use this [helper library](https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog) like this:

```
 BootstrapDialog.show({
    message:formHtml
   ,cssClass:'.form-dialog'
 });
```

I use this css:

```
 #ma-form-container{
            width:600px;
            height:100%;
        }
        
        
        #ma-form label
        {
            display:inline-block;
            text-align:right;
        }
```

I find that the form is much larger than the modal,I also tried using the css:

```
     #ma-form-container{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
```

y
I find that `$("#ma-form")` and `$("#ma-form-container")` are empty when the `modal`  is open.

## EDIT:

I have changed the template and removed the plugin:

```
     <div id="openModal" style="display: block;"><div class="modal fade form-dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Details</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
          <form class="form form-horizontal" role="form" id="ma-form">
            
              <div class="form-group">
                <span style="color:">
                  <label for="AUTHGRP" class="col-xs-3 control-label">AuthorizGroup</label>
                </span>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="AUTHGRP" id="AUTHGRP" placeholder="AuthorizGroup">
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            
              <div class="form-group">
                <span style="color:">
                  <label for="DESCRIPT" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Description</label>
                </span>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="DESCRIPT" id="DESCRIPT" placeholder="Description">
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            
              <div class="form-group">
                <span style="color:">
                  <label for="OBJECTTYPE" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Object type</label>
                </span>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OBJECTTYPE" id="OBJECTTYPE" placeholder="Object type">
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            
              <div class="form-group">
                <span style="color:">
                  <label for="PLANGROUP" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Planner group</label>
                </span>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PLANGROUP" id="PLANGROUP" placeholder="Planner group">
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            
              <div class="form-group">
                <span style="color:">
                  <label for="PLANPLANT" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Planning plant</label>
                </span>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PLANPLANT" id="PLANPLANT" placeholder="Planning plant">
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            
              <div class="form-group">
                <span style="color:">
                  <label for="EQUICATGRY" class="col-xs-3 control-label">EquipCategory</label>
                </span>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="EQUICATGRY" id="EQUICATGRY" placeholder="EquipCategory">
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            
              <div class="form-group">
                <span style="color:">
                  <label for="" class="col-xs-3 control-label"></label>
                </span>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  
                      <input type="" class="form-control" name="" id="" placeholder="">
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            
          </form>   
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="formSubmit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal --></div>
```

With this I am using this to open the dialog:

```
  $("#map-actions a").on("click",function(e){
                        event.preventDefault();
                         $("#openModal").html(formHtml);
                         $("#openModal").css("display","block");
                         
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your form you are using a wrong syntax for set an id attribute

change

```
id="#ma-form"
```

to

```
id="ma-form"
```

and it will work, dont forget to fix this recursively to all occurences of your fault

```
alert($('#ma-form').html())
```

will output the content instead of "undefined"

cheers

Comment: I changed the template to cut out the plugin,but the div does not open.